# How to display the time in this format?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, week-number

The time should be displayed like this `0000:00:0:00:00` to the user which stands for `YYYY:WW:D:HH:MM`. I will need methods to add/reduce/set the time.

How can I use PHP `DateTime()` to achieve this? It should always be displayed in this format, even if I only have one hour it should be displayed like this `0000:00:0:01:00`.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Your question is clear but the comments to the answers below seems as the question is not clear after all. Edit your question with some samples. What should be the input, and what should the output be?

Comment: What exactely is not clear?

Comment: Read my question, not just the first sentence.

Comment: As clearly stated, I start with `0000:00:0:00:00`, I need function to edit the time and the output should ALWAYS be in this format, e.g `0000:00:0:01:00` for a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo date('Y:m:j:h:i');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
Second argument for date is timestamp

Comment: But if I reduce the years to 1 for example, how could I still have 3 digits in front of the 1?

Comment: It will print 0001 year

Comment: I tried this `$date = new DateTime('2019-45-09 12:07');
echo $date->format('Y:w:d H:i');` and I get a fatal error.

Comment: Because you gave to constructor date 2019-45-09 45 month doesn't exists

Comment: $date = new DateTime('2019-05-09 12:07');
echo $date->format('Y:m:j:h:i');

Comment: I don't want the month to be displayed

Comment: Delete it) $date = new DateTime('2019-05-09 12:07'); echo $date->format('Y:j:h:i');

Comment: What is `j`? And where are the days?
Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: See this page https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php . It has table with explanation all format letters(for expample j Day of the month without leading zeros 1 to 31).

Answer (score 0):

Do it with `echo date('Y:W:j:H:i');`  [PHP Manual date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
Y   A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits           Examples: 1999 or 2003
W   ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday      Example: 42 (the 42nd week in the year)
m   Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros       01 through 12
j   Day of the month without leading zeros                      1 to 31
H   24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros                00 through 23
i   Minutes with leading zeros                                  00 to 59
```

---

For your issue refer to [How to create datetime from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58777696/6521116)    Here is the [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca9b74c5d04fe679b21c2ae99df85d68de5dd2bf)

```
$str = '2019-45-09 12:07';
$arr = explode(" ",$str);
$date_arr = explode("-",$arr[0]);
$time_arr = explode(":",$arr[1]);
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setISODate($date_arr[0],$date_arr[1],$date_arr[2])->setTime($time_arr[0],$time_arr[1]);
echo $date->format("Y-W-d H:i:s") . PHP_EOL;
$date->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
echo $date->format("Y-W-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Where are the weeks?

Comment: Also, how could I modify that value?

Comment: Modify what value?

Comment: I need a way to modify the date afterwards.

Comment: I tried using DateTime() but it messes up the format. See my comment on the other answer.

Comment: @termum Check my answer now.