# How to create datetime from week number

Tags: php, datetime, week-number

I use [DateTime::creaeFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create datetime from week number. But it always return false.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-W-d','2019-45-09');
var_dump($date);
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
```

---

**Solution**:

```
$date = (new DateTime())->setISODate($year,$week,$day)->setTime($hour,$minute,$second,$microseconds);
```

Comment: FYI, `W` is not a supported parameter for `createFromFormat`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php…

Comment: The comments on the manual page link to: http://lornajane.net/posts/2011/getting-dates-from-week-numbers-in-php

Comment: Thank you, that means I need to explode the string, then create the datetime, is is right?

Comment: Yes, `explode` it into three parts and pass them as ISO values.

Comment: `$date = (new DateTime())->setISODate($year,$week,$day)->setTime($hour,$minute,$second,$microseconds);`